# How to show my own robot model in Ruiz?

Tags: model, visualization, ros

I just get a question recently. 
Now I have got the URDF and STL file for my robot and I want to show it in the Rviz. How can I achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get your robot visible in Rviz you have to run node called *robot_state_publisher*.
That node parses given URDF (xarco) file and publish robot's frames given in parameter robot description, also provide some info for RViz to load model.

Good example is provided by Clearpath with Husky:
https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/indigo-devel/husky_description/launch/description.launch

Answer (score 0):

simply write a launchfile like this:

```
<launch>
<arg name="model" default="$(find your_package_name)/path_to_your_urdf/your_urdf.urdf"/>
<arg name="gui" default="true"/>

<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)" />
<param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>

<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf.rviz" required="true"/>

</launch>
```

it's recommended to outcomment the part with the rviz node for debugging so you don't have to always restart rviz. Instead, use `rosrun rviz rviz` to launch Rviz (make sure a roscore is running!)

joint_state_publisher let's you control your robot joints via a GUI, whereas robot_state_publisher actually publishes the joint_states to /tf, allowing Rviz obtaining correct transformations for your robot.

See: [ROS Wiki: robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher)